# python: read json data from file and append more data

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to read existing data from a json file and trying to append more data to the file using python (I'm a python newbie). Here is my existing data in data.json file which I read in my script:

```
{
    "Config1": {
        "TestCase1": {
            "Data1": 200,
            "Data2": 2715
        }
    },
    "Config2": {
        "TestCase1": {
            "Data1": 2710,
            "Data2": 2715
        }
    }
}
```

After reading I want to append TestCase2 data. This is what I'm doing:

```
with open("data.json") as json_file: #load existing data
    json_data = json.load(json_file)

test='TestCase2'
result=json_data
myConfigs = ['Config1','Config2']
for each, config in enumerate(myConfigs):
    result.update({config:{test:{'Data1':2600,'Data2':2900}}})
with open('data.json', 'a') as outfile:
    json.dump(result, outfile)
```

The new data in  data.json is not valid as pointed by [jsonLint](http://jsonlint.com). What am I doing wrong? Here is the new data

```
{
        "Config1": {
            "TestCase1": {
                "Data1": 200,
                "Data2": 2715
            }
        },
        "Config2": {
            "TestCase1": {
                "Data1": 2710,
                "Data2": 2715
            }
        }
    } {
        "Config1": {
            "TestCase2": {
                "Data1": 2600,
                "Data2": 2900
            }
        },
        "Config2": {
            "TestCase2": {
                "Data1": 2600,
                "Data2": 2900
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The dict in result.update looks wrong (no quotes on the keys), and the method for json should be `loads` and `dumps`...

Comment: @bozdoz `loads` uses strings `load` file objects (or anything that implements `read()` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to opening the file in the wrong mode (should be 'w'), you are also overwriting your old "config" trees by defining a new dict inline.

Instead of:

```
result.update({config:{test:{'Data1':2600,'Data2':2900}}})
```

Try this:

```
result[config][test] = {'Data1': 2600, 'Data2': 2900}
```

This should give you the result you are looking for with your example. It will let `result['Config1']['TestCase1']` persist while you add TestCase2. You may also need to make sure that the config tree exists by setting `result[config]` to `{}` if it's `None`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're appending the new JSON to the original JSON file here:

```
with open('data.json', 'a') as outfile:
    json.dump(result, outfile)
```

So you have two JSON objects in the same file as you can see:

```
...
            "Data2": 2715
        }
    }
} {  <--- original object ends here, new object starts here
    "Config1": {
...
```

JSONLint is expecting a single object, as will any JSON parser.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that the `dict1.update(dict2)` method overwrites `dict1` keys if the same exist in `dict2` hence the second object in your file doesn't have key =>`TestCase1`

Another problem is that (as pointed above) the file is opened in the wrong mode (Should be `w`) as `a` appends to the json file

You could try this:

```
with open("data.json") as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)

test='TestCase2'
result=json_data
myConfigs = ['Config1','Config2']
for each, config in enumerate(myConfigs):
    result[config].update({test:{'Data1':2600,'Data2':2900}})
with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(result, outfile)
```

Just `result[config].update(...` instead of `result.update({config:...`